# How to calculate the drawdown in Mysql with Window Functions?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, rdbms

I have this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

and i have populated that table with the following data:

```
insert into test (amount, group_id) values
(1,1), (3,1), (-4,1), (-2,1), (5,1), (10,1), (18,1), (-3,1), 
(-5,1), (-7,1), (12,1), (-9,1), (6,1), (0,1), (185,2), (-150,2)
```

The table is:

```
# id, amount, group_id
1, 1, 1
2, 3, 1
3, -4, 1
4, -2, 1
5, 5, 1
6, 10, 1
7, 18, 1
8, -3, 1
9, -5, 1
10, -7, 1
11, 12, 1
12, -9, 1
13, 6, 1
14, 0, 1
15, 185, 2
16, -150, 2
```

This is the query i am using right now:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, 
    t1.amount, 
    t1.cumsum, 
    (MAX(t1.cumsum) OVER (ORDER BY id RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - t1.cumsum) as drawdown    
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        id,
        amount,
        group_id,
        SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY id RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as cumsum        
    FROM 
        test
) as t1
order by drawdown desc
```

the query returns this output:

```
id, amount, cumsum, drawdown
10  -7  16  15
12  -9  19  12
9   -5  23  8
4   -2  -2  6
14  0   25  6
13  6   25  6
3   -4  0   4
8   -3  28  3
11  12  28  3
5   5   3   1
16  150 360 0
2   3   4   0
7   18  31  0
15  185 210 0
1   1   1   0
6   10  13  0
```

Just a fast clarification:
With the term "drawdown" (in this case) i mean the difference from the max cumsum of the value(field) AND the simple cumsum (cumulative sum).

I am not referring to any particular trading definition, i just need to difference between the biggest pick and the lowest. (obviously the highest pick must occour before the lowest = downtrend).

OK, my problem is that i need to group by the field `group_id`, if i add the group by clause on the query all the windows function will mess up.

***RESULT EXPECTED:***

I need to get a list grouped by group_id field that show the max drawdown **for each group**.

Edit: (@Akina)

```
group_id, drawdown
1    15
2    150
```

Comment: For those of us not familiar with the terminology can you add your expected output please.

Comment: *i need to group by the field group_id, if i add the group by clause on the query all the windows function will mess up.* It seems you must add `PARTITION BY group_id` into all window definitions...

Comment: @Akina if i add PARTITION BY by group_id i still see all the records, is it normal?

Comment: Of course. But each group will be calculated separately like only its data is present.

Comment: @Akina please could you give me an example, if i add PARTITION BY i still see the list of all the records, i only need to get one record per group

Comment: Publish expected result for shown sample data.

Comment: @Akina the data is already present (insert) i have added the expected result i need

Comment: I see 2 records for `group_id = 2`: `(185,2), (150,2)`. Please explain how do you obtain `dragdown = 35` for this group... see [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j8jS4zV89qN3zn8jDtNvdB/0).

Comment: @Akina it is the difference between the previous highest pick (inm this case there is only one value so it will take the first record has pick and the a subtraction 185-150 = 35

Comment: @AKina yeah with onle two records it does not work as expected, but do you understand my needs?

Comment: *and the a subtraction 185-150 = 35* WHY??? 1st record gives `cumsum=185` and `drawdown=185-185=0`. 2nd record gives `cumsum=185+150=335` and `drawdown=335-335=0`. Where 35 is taken from?

Comment: @Akina pardon my wrong, i miss the minus in front of 150 so in this case i need 135 dradown

Comment: Please look at my fiddle, especially on 2 bottom lines of 2nd output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211549/discussion-between-dail-and-akina).